# Unable to click on a button which is auto-focused by a script

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, functional-programming

I'm trying to click a button which is auto-focused by a script in the html.
I've tried both absolute path, relative path but no luck. pretty much anything I can think of. Attached is a screenshot which will display that the xpath is locating the element successfully on the web but when I use it in selenium, it can't find the element.
I've also tried waiting explicitly for 10 seconds for the element using a generic function. (Check the screenshot) This function is working for all other buttons that were called previously except for this one.

Something CAUGHT my eyes is that There's a method being called which auto-focuses the button. I might have to turn the focus to the entire window or the page in this case. I've also tried sending the enter key but still no luck.

Question_1: Does anyone have any solution?
Question_2: Does anyone know how to switch focus to the page?
Question_3: Or anything.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you receiving errors as a result of your attempts? That is, does the element exist or does Selenium return an error? If Selenium says the element exists, is visible and enabled, you should be able to click on it. It is possible that the xpath(locator) is not referencing the submit button.

Comment: Can you update the question with your code attempt in Text?

Comment: The problem was with iframe. I got it to work by switching the driver to the iframe. It worked like a charm after that. I appreciate all of your help with all the answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To switch focus to parent window/default content window you should use switchTo() method on driver instance.

```
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
```

OR

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

You can use following two statements to know which element is currently focused.

```
 driver.switchTo().activeElement();
 driver.getPageSource();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Script click instead of click. Like this, Hope this will help.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("SubmitButtonId"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to click on input tag , your script will fail. try to find correct locator only. it will help or try submit() function as you said, this element is auto selected.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you need to bring element in to view before clicking on the same:

the code for that is:
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", webElement);